# Python Regex Capture Only Certain Text

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to find functionality in python similar to the Ruby function scan. My goal is to grab all the text in-between two curly braces in a list. If there are multiple pairs of curly braces in the string, I want to have multiple entries in the list.

When I run this code:

```
 match = re.search(r'\{(.+)\}', request.params['upsell'])
 print match.group()
```

I match the right text. However, what is captured includes the curly braces. I don't want to include this text, I want to include everything in between, but not the curly braces Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
re.findall(r'\{(.+?)\}', request.params['upsell'])
```

This will return a list where each entry is the contents of a different group of curly braces.  Note that this will not work for nested braces.

The `?` after the `.+` will make it a lazy match (as opposed to greedy).  This means that the match will stop at the first "}", instead of continuing to match as many characters as possible and ending on the last closing brace.

`re.findall()` will search through your string and find all non-overlapping matches, and return the group.  Alternatively you could use `re.finditer()` which will iterate over Match objects, but then you would need to use `match.group(1)` to get only what it inside of the braces.  This is also what you would need to change in your example, `match.group()` returns the entire match not the captured group, for that you need to put the number for the group you want.

Answer (score 14):

Use `group(1)`, or lookbehinds/aheads. (Also, be sure to take the advice of F.J. and J.F. and use either `.+?` or `[^{}]*`

```
import re
match = re.search(r'\{(.+)\}', "asdfasd {asdf}asdfasdf")
print match.group(1)
```

or with lookbehinds/aheads:

```
import re
match = re.search(r'(?<=\{)(.+)(?=\})', "asdfasd {asdf}asdfasdf")
print match.group()
```

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> import re
>>> re.findall(r'{([^{}]*)}', '{a} { {b} c { {d} } }')
['a', 'b', 'd']
```